# Prevent iCloud window from opening on OSX 10.8 app launch

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, osx-mountain-lion, icloud

I have written an OSX app that uses iCloud document storage.  Whenever I open it in Mountain Lion (not on Lion), an iCloud window opens that looks like the following:

[image]

Is there a way to prevent this from happening on launch?

**Updates:**

1) `applicationShouldOpenUntitledFile:` is not getting called (yes, I'm sure I'm listening in my delegate.
2) If I force quit the app, the next time it opens, I don't get the dialog.  But, if I go through the normal Quit process, it does appear.

**Update 2 (also added as an answer, to help people that may stumble across this question in the future):**
The `applicationShouldOpenUntitledFile:` from the duplicate question was not working.  After lots of experimentation, I figured out that if I remove the `NSDocumentClass` key and value from my Info.plist in the `CFBundleDocumentTypes` array, the window is no longer opened.  I've added that answer to the duplicate question as well.

Comment: [Does this related question have the answer for you?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13825228/icloud-enabled-stop-the-open-file-displaying-on-application-launch?rq=1)

Comment: No -- although the symptoms are similar, the proposed solution doesn't work.  In my app - (BOOL) applicationShouldOpenUntitledFile:(NSApplication *)sender is not being called by the system.

Comment: I suggest you answer your own question. Update 2 above is really an answer. You can answer it, and at this point, after the 1 day wait, you can accept it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `applicationShouldOpenUntitledFile:` from [iCloud enabled - Stop the open file displaying on application launch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13825228/icloud-enabled-stop-the-open-file-displaying-on-application-launch?rq=1) was not working. After lots of experimentation, I figured out that if I remove the `NSDocumentClass` key and value from my `Info.plist` in the `CFBundleDocumentTypes` array, the window is no longer opened.

Comment: when I removed that makeWindowControllers for NSPersistentDocument subclass still doesnt get called. Only when I disable iCloud, it hides that window and calls makeWindowControllers

Answer (score 0):

Putting below codes in your App Delegate lets you bypass that iCloud pop up New Document screen. Tested for High Sierra.

```
-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    // Schedule "Checking whether document exists." into next UI Loop.
    // Because document is not restored yet. 
    // So we don't know what do we have to create new one.
    // Opened document can be identified here. (double click document file)
    NSInvocationOperation* op = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc]initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(openNewDocumentIfNeeded) object:nil];
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperation: op];
}

-(void)openNewDocumentIfNeeded
{
    NSUInteger documentCount = [[[NSDocumentController sharedDocumentController] documents]count];

    // Open an untitled document what if there is no document. (restored, opened).       
    if(documentCount == 0){
        [[NSDocumentController sharedDocumentController]openUntitledDocumentAndDisplay:YES error: nil];
    }
}
```